# The while loop doesn’t stop on a boolean condition

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I wrote a simple code to solve an artificial problem. I want the program to exit the loop body after `N =< 3`, but the iterations continue after the condition isn't met. Where did i go wrong?

```
int main(){

    uint8_t N = 0;
    int power = 1;
    std::cin >> N;

    while (N >= 4){
        power *= 3;
        N -= 3;
    }
        
    power *= N;
    std::cout << power;
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc 12.2.0. Flags -Wall -O2
```

I tried to use a loop `for (N; N >= 4; N -=3)`, but result didn't change.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/r6nYnWdsv

Comment: I can't reproduce either.

Comment: What value did you input for `N`?

Comment: @AdrianMole N is between 0 and 100.

Comment: maybe because overflow?    N is uint8_t,  if N is 1;  N-3 = 254;

Comment: please be more exact. What is the value of `N` that makes the loop not stop? If you enter `2` then after decrementing the value by 3 it is never `<4`. If `N` you enter is `>4` its a different story. Details matter. Please add example input in the question when thats required to reprduce the issue

Comment: @niu2x unsigneds don't overflow, they wrap around, but yeah thats most likely the reason

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number if 2 is entered, the loop won't start, so power will be 2. As already commented, the bug is not reproducible.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I I put the loop inside the `if (N > 4)` condition, but the result didn't change. For example, I want the output to be `18` when I enter `8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint8_t` is `char` type.

In stdint.h,

```
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
```

`'4'` will be resulted in integer `52` due to implicit casting.

You may just use `int` type if you are accepting number.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. When I looked at the values ​​of the debugger, I could not understand why it was adding characters to N.